# Laravel Pagination with ajax+jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.8

I was trying to use ajax and jQuery for one of my projects layout. I took help from some online sites to learn how to that. But even though I am doing what those resources did, somehow my ajax and jQuery code does not work properly

Blog Posts Part in profile.blade.php :

```
<div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> Blog Posts </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @if(count($posts))
                    <div id="userPosts">
                        @include('users.userPosts')
                    </div>
                @else
                    No Posts to show
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ajax and jQuery part in profile.blade.php :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let url = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/profile/user-posts?page='+url,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#userPosts').html(data);
                location.hash=url;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Route in web.php :

```
Route::get('/profile/user-posts','UserController@myPosts');
```

Controller function in UsersController :

```
public function myPosts(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::where('user_id',auth()->id())->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('users.showPosts')->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

**EDIT** : Bug in the route file [ UsersController not UserController ] and $request->ajax() condition usage

Comment: what do you mean not working properly? did you check your console log see wether you have an error or so?